# General rule for finding distribution of $\bar{X}$ of iid R.Vs?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Is there a general set of rules we can use to find out what $\bar{X}$ is for a set of iid R.Vs $X_1, ..., X_n$?

For example, If our R.V's have distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then the sum of the R.Vs have distribution $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$ and we divide through by $n$, using the rule that $c\times E(X)=cE(X)$ and $c \times Var(X)=c^2Var(X)$.

However, what happens for other distributions with different parameters?

For example the $Binom(N,\pi)$ or the $Poisson(\mu)$ or the $Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)$?

Essentially I am asking for a general rule to apply to parameters of distributions that will give me the parameter for the mean of the iid R.Vs.

Comment: Maybe look at the moment generating functions?

Comment: Indeed the characteristic functions $$\varphi_{\bar X}(t)=E(e^{it\bar X})\qquad \varphi_1(t)=E(e^{itX_1})$$ are related through the identity $$\varphi_{\bar X}(t)=\left(\varphi_1(t/n)\right)^n$$ and this determines entirely the distribution of $\bar X$. That, or convolutions...

Comment: The general relationship is pointed in above comments. I just want to add that only when the parameters are some location-scale parameters, or related to the first/second moments, and the distribution is "closed" under addition, you have some chance of obtaining a very nice and direct relationship between the of the original parameters and the sample mean.